# How to pass a callable as an argument to `functools.partial`

Tags: python-3.x, functools

This code

```py
import itertools
import functools

i = itertools.cycle(["1", "2"])

def f1():
    return next(i)

def f2(a):
    print(a)

f = functools.partial(f2, f1())

f()
f()
```

produces output `1 1`.
Is there an obvious way to prevent calculating `f1` when `f` is created, so result output would be `1 2`?

Comment: You could just pass the function `f1` itself as an argument, then evaluate it inside `f2`, like `print(a())`

Comment: I'd like to, but i can't because IRL f2 is from another package

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to ``partial`` in specific. Are you asking for lazy evaluation?

Comment: Yeap. Lazy evaluation within `partial`
And it is not possible as i suppose

Answer (score 1):

How about using closure instead of functools?

```py
import itertools

i = itertools.cycle(["1", "2"])

def f1():
    return next(i)

def f2(a):
    print(a)

def wrap(target, fun):
    def inner():
        target(fun())
    return inner

f = wrap(f2, f1)

f()  # 1
f()  # 2
```

Comment: Thx, it's great, but don't really want to change `f` interface. But without other options this is a only way, i suppose

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve the intended output using `lambda` instead of `functools.partial`:

```py
import itertools

i = itertools.cycle(["1", "2"])

def f1():
    return next(i)

def f2(a):
    print(a)

f = lambda: f2(f1())

f()
f()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
import functools

i = itertools.cycle(["1", "2"])

def f1(a):
    print(next(a))

f = functools.partial(f1, i)

f()
f()
```

Just moved work on argument been passed to the patched function